# Как починить грид?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Грид не работает:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  arrows: false
})

$('.left').click(function() {
  $('.slider').slick("slickPrev");
})

$('.right').click(function() {
  $('.slider').slick("slickNext");
})
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body{

font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
color: white;
}
#section0{
  background: url(bezimeni-27_E1v9oDX.png) no-repeat center/cover;

background-attachment: fixed ;
overflow-y: hidden;
height: 100vh;
}#section0 .p{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 34px;
  margin-top: 5%;
}#section0 .span{
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  padding:0 5px;}
  #section0 .span0{
    font-weight: 800;
  }#section0 .aside{
    margin-top: 8%;
    margin-left: 26%;

text-align: center;
color: black;
padding: 80px 140px ;
background: #fff;
width: 660px;
  }#section0 .p0{
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: 800;
margin-bottom: 5%;
  }
  #section0 .span1{
font-weight: 800;


  }  #section0 a{
padding: 13px 28px;
background: orange;
color: #fff;

text-decoration: none;

  }
#section1{
  height: 100vh;
  background: silver;
overflow-y: hidden;
}
#section2{
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;

}#section2 .grid{
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 200px);
grid-gap: 100px 100px;
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}







.slider {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.left {

   float:left;
position:relative;
bottom: 194px;

}

.left:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.right {
  float:right;
position:relative;
bottom: 194px;


}

.right:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}


#div{
position: relative;
width: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="0.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="1.css"><link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="section0">
<p class="p"><span class="span">THE</span> <span class="span0">MOON</span></p>
<aside class="aside">
<p class="p0">ПОЛЕТЫ НА ЛУНУ С <span class="span1">40% СКИДКОЙ</span></p>
  <p class="p1">Узнайте первыми об уникальном предложении и получите возможность
заказать десятидневный тур по цене пятидневного</p>
  <br><a href="#" >ПРИНЯТЬ УЧАСТИЕ</a>
  </aside>
    </section>


<section id="section1">
  <div class="slider">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="" />
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id='div'><img src="http://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-10_fPO5E8V.png#size_25x45" alt="" class="left">
    <img src="http://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-9_excx7Mu.png#size_24x45" alt="" class="right"></div>


</section>

<section id="section2">
<div class="grid">
<div class="">
  <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/57561/i1_SlAtGvo.png#size_45x44" alt="">
  <p>Опишите одно из самых
  выдающихся
  преимуществ вашего
  предложения</p>
</div>
<div class="">
  <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/57561/i2_KF1GZb3.png#size_43x34" alt="">
  <p>Сообщите о второй
  по важности черте
  вашего продукта
  или сервиса</p>

</div>
<div class="">
  <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/57561/i3_OaFkVCV.png#size_45x45" alt="">

  <p>Обратите внимание
  на еще один факт
  касательно вашего
  предложения</p>

</div>
<div class="">
  <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/57561/i4_dGwNQmg.png#size_33x48" alt="">
  <p>Расскажите о вашей
  компании, обозначив
  ее сильные стороны
  и преимущества</p>

</div>
</div>

</section>










<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
  <script src="0.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

css #section2 .grid необходимо добавить `display: grid;`.
Судя по вашим вопросам вам нужно быть более внимательным, так же научиться на СО помечать правильные ответы и просто научиться читать документации.
Так же не советовал бы использовать в css id и переделать всё на классы.

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  arrows: false
})

$('.left').click(function() {
  $('.slider').slick("slickPrev");
})

$('.right').click(function() {
  $('.slider').slick("slickNext");
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
}

#section0 {
  background: url(bezimeni-27_E1v9oDX.png) no-repeat center/cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

#section0 .p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 34px;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

#section0 .span {
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

#section0 .span0 {
  font-weight: 800;
}

#section0 .aside {
  margin-top: 8%;
  margin-left: 26%;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  padding: 80px 140px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 660px;
}

#section0 .p0 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

#section0 .span1 {
  font-weight: 800;
}

#section0 a {
  padding: 13px 28px;
  background: orange;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#section1 {
  height: 100vh;
  background: silver;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#section2 {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#section2 .grid {
  display: grid;
  /* добавленно */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 200px);
  grid-gap: 100px 100px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.slider {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 194px;
}

.left:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 194px;
}

.right:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#div {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="0.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="1.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>
  <section id="section0">
    <p class="p"><span class="span">THE</span> <span class="span0">MOON</span></p>
    <aside class="aside">
      <p class="p0">ПОЛЕТЫ НА ЛУНУ С <span class="span1">40% СКИДКОЙ</span></p>
      <p class="p1">Узнайте первыми об уникальном предложении и получите возможность заказать десятидневный тур по цене пятидневного</p>
      <br><a href="#">ПРИНЯТЬ УЧАСТИЕ</a>
    </aside>
  </section>


  <section id="section1">
    <div class="slider">
      <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="" />
      </div>

    </div>
    <div id='div'><img src="http://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-10_fPO5E8V.png#size_25x45" alt="" class="left">
      <img src="http://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-9_excx7Mu.png#size_24x45" alt="" class="right"></div>


  </section>

  <section id="section2">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="">
        <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/57561/i1_SlAtGvo.png#size_45x44" alt="">
        <p>Опишите одно из самых выдающихся преимуществ вашего предложения
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/57561/i2_KF1GZb3.png#size_43x34" alt="">
        <p>Сообщите о второй по важности черте вашего продукта или сервиса</p>

      </div>
      <div class="">
        <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/57561/i3_OaFkVCV.png#size_45x45" alt="">

        <p>Обратите внимание на еще один факт касательно вашего предложения
        </p>

      </div>
      <div class="">
        <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/57561/i4_dGwNQmg.png#size_33x48" alt="">
        <p>Расскажите о вашей компании, обозначив ее сильные стороны и преимущества</p>

      </div>
    </div>

  </section>










  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
  <script src="0.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```